# Wix: Hidden Lightbox in Mobile view still shows some shade

Tags: javascript, velo

In the mobile version of my website, I wanted to hide a lightbox linked to a box and redirect to a different page by clicking the box.

I used the following code to hide the lightbox.

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'; 
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

$w.onReady(function () {
    if(wixWindow.formFactor === "Mobile"){
        $w('#lightbox1').hide();
    }
});
```

I then used the following code to redirect to a different page by clicking the box.

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'; 
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

$w.onReady(function () {
    if(wixWindow.formFactor === "Mobile"){
        $w('#box3').onClick(function(){
            wixLocation.to('/flagevt-mob');
        });
    }
    
});
```

However, in mobile view, I do get redirected to a different page while clicking on `box3` and the lightbox does get hidden. Nevertheless, there is some shade and I have to click on the screen to get rid of that shade. It is almost like bursting a bubble.

Could someone please help with why this is happening?

Here is a [link](https://evct87.wixsite.com/my-site/) to the site. You may view it in both desktop and mobile view. The box corresponding to `box3` can be identified with the text "FLAGSHIP EVENTS" on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do but if you want to "display a lightbox on the desktop and redirect to a page on mobile upon a button click" you should do this instead:

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'; 
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

$w.onReady(function () {
    $w('#box3').onClick(function(){
       if(wixWindow.formFactor === "Mobile"){
           wixLocation.to('/flagevt-mob');
       }else{
           wixWindow.openLightbox("LightboxName");
       }
    });
});
```

Do **not** link the button to your lightbox using [this method](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-adding-a-link-to-a-button)

Comment: Make sure to use the lightbox's name and not it's ID when calling the openLightbox() function. And I think @Shan is correct. It looks like you're using the link panel to open the lightbox. A side point: there is no hide() function for a lightbox, you would need to use the close() function.